# Applied Hierarchical Modeling in Ecology function sim.fn not found

Tags: r, runtime-error, distribution, modeling

In the book "Applied Hierarchical Modeling in Ecology" (ISBN: 978-0-12-801378-6), the first function called fails immediately.

```
library("unmarked")
tmp <- sim.fn( quad.size = 10, cell.size = 1, intensity = 1)

sim.fn( quad.size = 10, cell.size = 1, intensity = 1)
```

I get the message:

```
Error: could not find function "sim.fn"
```

I have verified that the library "unmarked" is properly loaded and installed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

There are further packages to install, as sim.fn is located in the AHMbook library:

```
install.packages(c("unmarked", "plotrix", "sp", "raster", "RandomFields", "coda"))
install.packages("AHMbook", repos = "http://mikemeredith.net/R")

library("unmarked")
library("AHMbook")

tmp <- sim.fn( quad.size = 10, cell.size = 1, intensity = 1)
```